# type mismatch in java?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have the below piece of code:

```
public class AClass {
    public AClass() {
        System.out.println("Constructor A");
    }
}

public class BClass extends AClass{
    public BClass(){
        System.out.println("Constructor B");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BClass b = new BClass();
    }
}
```

I changed the code as seen below:

```
public class AClass {
    public AClass() {
        System.out.println("Constructor A");
    }
}

public class BClass extends AClass{
    public BClass(){
        System.out.println("Constructor B");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BClass b = new AClass();
    }
}
```

In the second code snippet, i am getting a  type mismatch error for this change `BClass b = new AClass();` .

I am learning java and i want to understand the deeper meaning of the error and I want to know why the error in the second code snippet?.

Comment: `AClass` is not a `BClass` so you can't pretend it is.  What is your doubt?

Comment: `BClass extends AClass` makes every `BClass` object reference a valid `AClass` object reference, but not the other way around.

Comment: Do you want `AClass a = new BClass();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you say; a Dog is a type of Animal like

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() { }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    public void meow() { }
}

Animal a = new Dog(); // is ok.
```

But you can't say; an Animal is a type of Dog.

```
Dog d = new Animal(); // not ok.
d.bark(); // Animal doesn't have a bark();
```

Comment: You forgot the .meow method in the class Cat :3

Comment: @Onza I was tempted... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do `AClass b = new BClass();` but not `BClass b = new AClass();` because simply `AClass` is parent of `BClass`. In polymorphism it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AClass a = new BClass();` instead.

The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says that

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S

in your example, that means objects of type A may be replaced with objects of type B.  You're trying to do it the other way around.  What the principle is saying is that when you say that B is a subtype of A, you can treat all instances of B as if they were A.  For instance, all dogs can be treated as if they were mammals.

What your example is trying to do is create a mammal and treat it like a dog.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform `downcasting` . To make this code work just change your code with the below one :

```
public class AClass {
    public AClass() {
        System.out.println("Constructor A");
    }
}

public class BClass extends AClass{
    public BClass(){
        System.out.println("Constructor B");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass b = new BClass();
        doDownCasting(b);
    }

private static void doDownCasting(AClass a){
    if(a instance of BClass){
    BClass bClass = (BClass)a; // do the downcasting here
}
}

}
```